# Creating database & schema before rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a RoR 5 app which uses MySQL for testing and development. The MySQL server has a `development` database created, but the `testing` database is missing (thus specs aren't running).

I could create the database on my own, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can make RoR create it for me when I run `rspec spec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create 
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask if there is a way RoR can create the database & schema for me just by running `rspec spec` (without running anything else).

Comment: Does it makes sense to teach RSpec a trick that is only needed once?